# How change layout over ajax

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I have ajax app, where links call actions by ajax, which can change 3 parts of layout.

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->header = $this->ajaxView->render('header.phtml');
$data->footer = $this->ajaxView->render('footer.phtml');
$data->content = $this->ajaxView->render('content.phtml');

echo Zend_Json::encode($data);
```

This is good, but I need sometimes change more then some sections. Ideally I would like change whole layout with diffirent headers and main html. Normally I can do it such way:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('different-layout');
```

But it doesn't work in ajax. Is some posibility to do that with ajax?

Comment: everything is possible, it does not mean it should be done that way. What you're trying to achieve is very weird.

Comment: Wierd? How solve Ajax app effectively?